# считать оценку выставленную товару через foreach

Tags: php

Есть поле с комментариями пользователей, которые оставили отзыв товару, в комментарии помимо текста есть число от 1 до 5, хранящееся в бд. Вопрос как вывести циклом это число? Т.е. я хочу добиться чтобы в зависимости от числа рисовалось необходимое количество звезд: число 1 - 1 звезда, 2 - 2 и т.д. Как этого добиться?

Comment: как далеко вы продвинусь, в чем проблема?

Comment: проблема в том что я могу вывести оценки в цикле через условие (если цифра 1, то ставим одну звезду и т.д.), но мне нужно чтобы это все работало без условия, просто циклом.

Comment: из базы вы достать можете? в каком виде вы это все получаете? как выглядит ваш цикл?

Comment: @Денис что то подход странный у вас. Делается все наоборот. Есть 5 звезд, и им проставляется класс, например `active` до числа которое у человека. А если ты хочешь все же сделать как ты хочешь. У тебя будет цикл в цикле по звездочкам. Не вижу проблемы этого сделать. Посмотрите в интернете, очень много скриптов рейтинга, написанных в 5 строчек, и со звездами

Comment: В комментарии в какой позиции находится число? Можно в начале достать его через `substr` а потом либо цикл делать, если там еще какие-то инструкции, либо `str_repeat`применить ..... пример... комментарий `$str = 'привет чувак_4';
$num = substr($str, -1); 
echo str_repeat('*', (int)$num);` ...... но это если число точно находится в конце или в начале...а не в произвольном месте

Comment: Всем спасибо за комментарии, проблему решил через цикл for.

Comment: @Денис Интересно на это взглянуть

Comment: @АлексейШиманский внутри цикла: `<?php foreach ($data as $productItem): ?>` сделал так: `<?php $value=$productItem["Mark"];
                                        for ($i=0; $i<$value; $i++)
                                            echo '<span class="fa fa-star"></span>';
                                        ?>`

Comment: проще `echo str_repeat('<span class="fa fa-star"></span>', $value);` имхо....без всяких циклов

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, возьму на вооружение)